# Google Drive Watch Resource URI returns 403

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm a little stuck. I'm connected to the google drive client via a service account and I can view + download resources.

My Code:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from httplib2 import Http
import httplib2
import os
import io
import uuid

def watch_file(service, file_id, channel_id, channel_type, channel_address):
    """Watch for all changes to a user's Drive.

    Args:
    service: Drive API service instance.
    file_id: ID of the file to watch.
    channel_id: Unique string that identifies this channel.
    channel_type: Type of delivery mechanism used for this channel.
    channel_address: Address where notifications are delivered.

    Returns:
    The created channel if successful, None otherwise.
    """
    body = {
    'id': channel_id,
    'type': channel_type,
    'address': channel_address
    }
    try:
        return service.files().watch(fileId=file_id, body=body).execute()
    except ValueError as error:
        print ('An error occurred: %s' % error)
    return None


scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('test-service-account-project-294621-23bc75e9e4fb.json', scopes)

http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())
drive = build('drive', 'v3', http=http_auth)

channel_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
channel_type = 'web_hook'
channel_address = '/my/remote/server/address'

watch_file(drive, '{resource-id}', channel_id, channel_type, channel_address)
```

When I try to `watch` a specific resource the request goes through and I get the following response:

```
{
   "kind":"api#channel",
   "id":"b7fef95a-194a-4ba9-befb-8ac19bcdb8e3",
   "resourceId":"PxMhSDUDVo1YKsVHkC0JGUKqpz8",
   "resourceUri":"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{resource-id}?acknowledgeAbuse=false&alt=json&supportsAllDrives=false&supportsTeamDrives=false&alt=json",
   "expiration":"1604634553000"
}
```

From my understanding, the above response snippet looks correct but when I search the `resourceId` uri in my browser, I'm presented to the below response:

```
{
   "error":{
      "errors":[
         {
            "domain":"usageLimits",
            "reason":"dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
            "message":"Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
            "extendedHelp":"https://code.google.com/apis/console"
         }
      ],
      "code":403,
      "message":"Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
   }
}
```

Note, I have a server running with my `watch` configured to a deployed server endpoint. I can see requests come through but the watch body is empty and the resourceUri contains 403.
This smells weird and is confusing because my client is configured correctly i.e I'm making requests through the API yet I'm receiving `Daily Limit` issues. It's as if the `watch` POST requires some other auth passed in (I tried adding an API key but no luck).

Thanks

**Edit:**
I'm interested in this `resourceUri` because I figure there is more information to unpack. With that said, after reading more about the notification expected output, I think the notification response I'm seeing is correct i.e headers + no body- but I don't think I should see a 403 in the resourceUri.

Notification response from server

```
2020-11-06T14:11:56.760215+00:00 app[web.1]: HEADERS: Connection: close
2020-11-06T14:11:56.760216+00:00 app[web.1]: X-Goog-Channel-Expiration: Fri, 06 Nov 2020 15:04:03 GMT
2020-11-06T14:11:56.760219+00:00 app[web.1]: User-Agent: APIs-Google; (+https://developers.google.com/webmasters/APIs-Google.html)
2020-11-06T14:11:56.760220+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Length: 0
2020-11-06T14:11:56.760220+00:00 app[web.1]: Host: {host}
2020-11-06T14:11:56.760221+00:00 app[web.1]: Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,br
2020-11-06T14:11:56.760221+00:00 app[web.1]: Accept: */*
2020-11-06T14:11:56.760222+00:00 app[web.1]: X-Forwarded-Proto: https
2020-11-06T14:11:56.760222+00:00 app[web.1]: Total-Route-Time: 0
2020-11-06T14:11:56.760223+00:00 app[web.1]: X-Goog-Resource-Id: {resource-id}
2020-11-06T14:11:56.760223+00:00 app[web.1]: X-Forwarded-Port: 443
2020-11-06T14:11:56.760223+00:00 app[web.1]: X-Forwarded-For: 66.249.88.175
2020-11-06T14:11:56.760225+00:00 app[web.1]: X-Goog-Resource-Uri: {resource-uri}
2020-11-06T14:11:56.760225+00:00 app[web.1]: X-Goog-Message-Number: 473340
2020-11-06T14:11:56.760226+00:00 app[web.1]: Connect-Time: 0
2020-11-06T14:11:56.760226+00:00 app[web.1]: X-Goog-Resource-State: update
2020-11-06T14:11:56.760226+00:00 app[web.1]: X-Request-Id: {request-id}
2020-11-06T14:11:56.760227+00:00 app[web.1]: Via: 1.1 vegur
2020-11-06T14:11:56.760227+00:00 app[web.1]: X-Goog-Channel-Id: {channel-id}
2020-11-06T14:11:56.760227+00:00 app[web.1]: X-Goog-Changed: children
2020-11-06T14:11:56.760228+00:00 app[web.1]: X-Request-Start: 1604671916756
2020-11-06T14:11:56.760228+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-06T14:11:56.760229+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-06T14:11:56.760229+00:00 app[web.1]: BODY: None
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code

Comment: Can you provide the code related to the `watch` request? Also, can you provide the code related to a notification you are receiving? And what do you mean by `when I search the resourceId uri`? Why do you need to `search` this uri?

Comment: @Iamblichus I edited my response above. I don't need to search the resource uri but given I did and I see a 403 it smells weird to me. In other words, it should be a version-specific identifier for the watched resource and not a 403.

Comment: Define `search the resourceId uri`. Do you mean you are trying to access this uri? How are you doing that?

Comment: @Iamblichus I simply paste the uri into my browser and the error is displayed as json.

Comment: @DaImTo ^ I included my code above

Comment: You need to be authenticated in order to fetch this resource, it's not public. When you're just trying to access the uri with your browser you're not providing any authentication token. Because of this, you get a 403 error. This is to be expected.

Comment: @Iamblichus you make a very good point lolol